# Android: Setting view to visible in AsyncTask's PreExecute causing error

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I have a `ProgressBar` in my layout:

```
<ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading_pb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

I make it "GONE" in my `onCreate`,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        intent_data=intent.getExtras().getString("shipid");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shipment_event_finding);
        //loading=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.loader_tv);
        loading=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.loading_pb);
        shipid_tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.shipid_val_tv);
        data=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.events_tl);
        viewmap=(Button)findViewById(R.id.view_map_btn);
        context=this;
        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        shipid_tv.setText(intent_data);
        new EventFindAsyncTask().execute();
    }
```

Now in my `AsyncTask`, I want to make it visible in preExecute and GONE again in postExecute, Here is my `AsyncTask`

```
private class EventFindAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>{


        protected void onPreExecute(){
            //loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params){

                    String s;
                    String keyval=intent_data;
                    String orgcode=MainActivity.un.getText().toString();
                    JSONObject jsonobj=null, shipmentcodesend=null;
                    try{
                            jsonobj=new JSONObject(--Some huge JSON--);

                    }
                    catch(JSONException je){
                        Log.e("ShipmentEventFindingActivity.EventFindAsyncTask","JSON error" , je);
                        //ErrorDialog displayerror=new ErrorDialog(je, context);
                        //displayerror.showDialog();
                    }



                    System.out.println("Made jsonobject");
                    System.out.println(jsonobj.toString());
                    Log.d("EventFindAsyncTask.doInBackground", "gonna post");
                    JSONConnectorPost connector1=new JSONConnectorPost(jsonobj, getString(R.string.PIDsearch_url), MainActivity.cookieStore.getCookies());
                    JSONObject result=connector1.connectClient();
                    Log.d("EventFindAsyncTask.doInBackground", "Done post");
                    s=result.toString();
                    int responsecode=connector1.getResponsecode();

                    try{
                        String cacheID=result.getString("cacheId");
                        shipmentcodesend=new JSONObject(---Another huge JSON---);
                    }
                    catch(JSONException je){
                        Log.e("ShipmentEventFindingActivity.EventFindAsyncTask","JSON error" , je);
                        //ErrorDialog displayerror=new ErrorDialog(je, context);
                        //displayerror.showDialog();
                    }

                    System.out.println("Made shipmentcodesend");
                    System.out.println(shipmentcodesend.toString());

                    JSONConnectorPost connector2=new JSONConnectorPost(shipmentcodesend, getString(R.string.PIDsearch_url),MainActivity.cookieStore.getCookies());
                    shipmentcodes=connector2.connectClient();

                    return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){

            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

.
.
.
.
.
.
Lot of other stuff
.
.
.

        }
```

Now as long as the  line `loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` is commented, everything works perfectly. But as soon as I uncomment it, The `ProgressBar` does display, but the `doInBackground` stops at this part of the code:

```
Log.d("EventFindAsyncTask.doInBackground", "gonna post");
                        JSONConnectorPost connector1=new JSONConnectorPost(jsonobj, getString(R.string.PIDsearch_url), MainActivity.cookieStore.getCookies());
                        JSONObject result=connector1.connectClient();
                        Log.d("EventFindAsyncTask.doInBackground", "Done post");
```

I get the "gonna post", but I dont get the "Done post", and the `ProgressBar` is forever loading. Note that the program works without the loading bar and I've used the JSONConnector classes in ~5 other places in my app where they are working perfectly. The problem arises only when the `ProgressBar` is made visible. Any solutions?

Comment: You want to display progressbar only during background process?

Comment: @Aniruddha yes, the JSONConnect.connectClient() takes about 6-7 seconds where the screen just seems idle. I want to show a ProgressBar for this duration of the doInBackground.

Comment: Check my answer. You need to remove ProgressDialog from xml file and do the edit according to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to display the ProgressDialog only during the background process.

Call AsyncTask like `new EventFindAsyncTask(ClassName.this).execute();` and remove `ProgressDialog` from layout.

```
private class EventFindAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>{

     ProgressDialog pd ;
     private Context _context;


public EventFindAsyncTask(Context context) {
        _context = context;
    }

        protected void onPreExecute ()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(_context);
        pd.setTitle("Processing");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();

    }

        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params){

                    String s;
                    String keyval=intent_data;
                    String orgcode=MainActivity.un.getText().toString();
                    JSONObject jsonobj=null, shipmentcodesend=null;
                    try{
                            jsonobj=new JSONObject(--Some huge JSON--);

                    }
                    catch(JSONException je){
                        Log.e("ShipmentEventFindingActivity.EventFindAsyncTask","JSON error" , je);
                        //ErrorDialog displayerror=new ErrorDialog(je, context);
                        //displayerror.showDialog();
                    }



                    System.out.println("Made jsonobject");
                    System.out.println(jsonobj.toString());
                    Log.d("EventFindAsyncTask.doInBackground", "gonna post");
                    JSONConnectorPost connector1=new JSONConnectorPost(jsonobj, getString(R.string.PIDsearch_url), MainActivity.cookieStore.getCookies());
                    JSONObject result=connector1.connectClient();
                    Log.d("EventFindAsyncTask.doInBackground", "Done post");
                    s=result.toString();
                    int responsecode=connector1.getResponsecode();

                    try{
                        String cacheID=result.getString("cacheId");
                        shipmentcodesend=new JSONObject(---Another huge JSON---);
                    }
                    catch(JSONException je){
                        Log.e("ShipmentEventFindingActivity.EventFindAsyncTask","JSON error" , je);
                        //ErrorDialog displayerror=new ErrorDialog(je, context);
                        //displayerror.showDialog();
                    }

                    System.out.println("Made shipmentcodesend");
                    System.out.println(shipmentcodesend.toString());

                    JSONConnectorPost connector2=new JSONConnectorPost(shipmentcodesend, getString(R.string.PIDsearch_url),MainActivity.cookieStore.getCookies());
                    shipmentcodes=connector2.connectClient();

                    return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){


        try
        {
            if (pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}


.
.
.
.
Lot of other stuff
.
.
.

        }
```

Comment: I'll try this, but I saw on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html , it says avoid ProgressDialogs and use ProgressBars

Comment: it didn't help... it still shows gonna post and then gets stuck.

Comment: stuck? what is happening?

Comment: Nothing, it loads forever, if I press home button it closes app and THEN I see it downloads JSON and I get Done post. Even before with the ProgressBar same thing, as long as I stay on same screen nothing, if I press back to go to previous screen or press home, then download happens and I get done post. I don't understand why this is happening at all.

Comment: You have to take internet speed into consideration. Let me check again.

Comment: my internet speed is about 20 Mbps... and doInBackground finishes in 5-10sec without the progressbar/dialog, so that shouldn't be a problem... I've been stuck on this for about 20 hours till now :'(

Comment: Do one this, change last parameter of AsyncTask i.e `JSONObject` to `String`. And `protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result)` to `protected void onPostExecute(String result)`. Check after doing these modifications. Then create that String result to `JSONObject` like `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you execute `setVisibility(View.GONE)` in **onCreate thread** and `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` in **another thread (AsyncTask execute a new thread in background)**

I don't know why GONE and VISIBLE doesn't work well in different threads but I would tell you try something like this:

`1) In your layout.xml` set `android:visibility="gone"`

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/loading_pb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

`2)` **remove** `loading.setVisibility(View.GONE)` from your `onCreate()`

`3) In your AsyncTask`

```
private class EventFindAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>{


    protected void onPreExecute(){
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params){
        // your code...

        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){

        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
```

**`Other possible solution:`** you can try with `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){});` take a look at this

```
private class EventFindAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>{


            protected void onPreExecute(){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                       loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                            
                       }
                    });
            }

            protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params){
                // your code...

                return result;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                          loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);                            
                       }
                    });


            }
```

I hope this help you.